# How to remove empty lines in VS Code?

Tags: visual-studio-code

Is there a better way to remove the empty rows? Currently I'm deleting them manually but it's a pain.

[image: VSC]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's an extension [Remove empty lines](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=usernamehw.remove-empty-lines)

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Found a way is to use this in Find/Replace

```
^$\n
```

Also make sure to enable: Regular Expression

But i wish there was a script to run this.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with a macro as you wished for in your answer.  You will need a macro extension: [multiCommand](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ryuta46.multi-command).

In your settings:

```
  "multiCommand.commands": [

    {
      "command": "multiCommand.removeEmptyLines",
      // "interval": 50,
      "sequence": [
        {
          "command": "type",
          "args": {
            "text": "^\\n"
          }
        },
        "cursorHomeSelect",
        "editor.action.clipboardCutAction",
        "editor.action.startFindReplaceAction",
        "editor.action.clipboardPasteAction",

        //  focus to the replace input
        "editor.action.startFindReplaceAction",

        // clear the replace input, if any
        "editor.action.clipboardCutAction",

        "editor.action.replaceAll"
      ]
    }
  ]
```

It is tricky because you cannot directly write into the find widget (even with a longer delay interval).  But you can print out what you want to find, "`^\\n`", select it, cut it and open the find widget and it will auto-populate the find field with the clipboard contents.  [Note the extra escape "^\n" is necessary here.]

Then there are some more commands to clear any pre-existing replace text you may have in the replace input field.

Also, as you know, you must have the "`Use Regular Expression`" option toggled on.  Unfortunately, that is a ***toggle***, there is no command for simply turning it on.  So the macro above can't invoke the toggle command - if you already had it on it would toggle off and the find would not work.  So this macro must assume you already have "`Use Regular Expression`" option toggled on.  I always leave it on and almost never find I need to toggle it off temporarily.

In your keybindings.json, set up whatever keybinding you would like:

```
{
    "key": "ctrl+alt+u",
    "command": "multiCommand.removeEmptyLines",
},
```

and then invoke that keybinding on any open line and it will trigger the macro - removing all open lines in the file (except any empty line at the very end of the file because there is no \n at the end of it).